# Does the Lie derivative of a harmonic form with respect to a killing vector field vanish

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hodge-theory

On the wikipedia page for Killing vector fields under 'properties' it is stated that if $X$ is a Killing vector field and $\omega$ is a harmonic differential form then $\mathcal{L}_{X}\omega=0$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field#Properties

It seems like this should be true but I can't find it stated anywhere else except for the online previews of a couple of books which I don't have access to. I have tried to show this using the formula for the Lie derivative of a form $\mathcal{L}_{X}\omega=d(i_{X}\omega)+i_{X}(d\omega)$ along with the co-closure condition on $\omega$ and Killing's equation but I'm not really sure where to go.

**So, my question is:** is this true and if so, what direction should I go in to try and show it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here some facts those lead you for a solution:

For any p-form $\omega$ follows:

1. $d(L_X\omega)=L_X(d\omega)$.
2. $L_X(*\omega)=(\text{div} X)*\omega+*[(L_Xg)\cdot\omega]+*(L_X\omega)$. (See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14991/commutator-of-lie-derivative-and-codifferential/194809#194809))
3. $\text{div}X=\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(L_Xg)$. Use definition of divergence and Lie derivative. (If you prefer, [here a solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2146233/divergence-of-vector-fields-and-the-trace-of-the-lie-derivative-of-the-metric))

Now, if $X$ is Killing, then itens 2 and 3 gives

4. $L_X(*\omega)=*(L_X\omega)$

But, by definition, when $(M,g)$ is compact and oriented, $\delta:=(-1)^{n(p-1)+1}*d*$, thus, from itens 1 and 4 we obtain

5. $\delta(L_X\omega)=L_X(\delta\omega)$

Since $\Delta=d\delta+\delta d$, we have from itens 1 and 5 for a Killing field

6. $\Delta(L_X\omega)=L_X(\Delta\omega)$

Now, for $\omega$ harmonic form, from item 6:

7. $\Delta(L_X\omega)=0$. Thus, $L_X\omega$ is a harmonic form as well.

Last step: Show that item 7 implies that $L_X\omega$ is equal zero.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I'm still struggling to show that item 7 implies the Lie derivative is equal to zero though, any tips on how to do so?

Comment: @DiegoMath If I may, I would like to know how you would show Cartan's magic formula without using 1. The proof of Cartan's formula I know uses 1, and 1 just relies on the fact that the exterior differential commutes with pullbacks, hence with the Lie derivative.

Comment: @Didier You are right, I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Others have given a proof when the manifold is compact. The result is false in general if the manifold is non-compact. Consider for instance $$f = x^2 - y^2$$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $f$ is not preserved by any non-zero Killing field. Nor is the harmonic 1-form $\omega = df$ (which is also exact and non-zero).

Answer (score 2):

For completing the proof consider the following lemma:

**Lemma:** If $\psi$ is exact (i.e. $\psi=d\eta$) and coclosed (i.e. $\delta\psi=0)$ then $\psi =0$.

This is easy to prove: Consider the induced inner product $\langle\!\langle., .\rangle\!\rangle$ that $d$ and $\delta$ are [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#On_manifolds) (i.e. $\langle\!\langle dA, B\rangle\!\rangle= \langle\!\langle A, \delta B\rangle\!\rangle$) w.r.t. that inner product. Then compute $\|\psi\|^2=\langle\!\langle\psi, \psi\rangle\!\rangle$.

(**Hint for rest of proof:** ${\cal L}_X\omega=d(i_X(\omega))+0=d(\text{something})\implies$ ${\cal L}_X\omega$ it is exact.).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess you could also arrive at the conclusion using Hodge's theorem. The Lie derivative of the harmonic form is exact and so it's cohomologous to zero. But then it is also harmonic and by Hodge's theorem the only harmonic form in the same cohomology class as zero is zero.

Comment: @DanielBaldwin: Where this fact comes from? I think it proof finally uses the above lemma!